# Change Bigcouch hostname

Tags: hostname, bigcouch

Is there any elegant way to change the Bigcouch hostname?  Bigcouch just automatically assumes it's name is bigcouch@FQDN so that is sprinkled through out all the databases you create on it.  When you change the FQDN Bigcouch craps it's pants and you can't do anything.

I have tried to manually go through the 5986 admin port and change all the FQDN references which then appears to give me 5984 access and editing ability again. It's not documented at all so it's just a crude hack that may or may not work properly.

Perhaps there is some more elegant way?  Seems kind of primitive to have to blow away a server and re-add it to a cluster in order to do this.